# Creating and Updating many to many relationships in C# asp.net MVC with Linq2Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, many-to-many, crud, nerddinner

I have created a web app in MVC following the NerdDinner tutorial.  I have 2 fields that have many to many relationship with my "dinner".  For each "dinner", I need to be able to select one or more Companies from a Company table and one or more Services from a Service table.  I've been reading blogs and forums for 2 days, but can't seem to figure it out.  I have a ServicetoDinner table with foreign keys to the service and the dinner, and the same for the Companies.  I know how to loop through to display them, but I don't know how to select multiple companies and/or services when creating a new "dinner" and how to save them.

I'm getting frustrated.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean that you "don't know how to select companies and/or services when creating a new "dinner" and how to save them"?

Comment: I edited to include the word "multiple". I know how to make a drop-down box to select 1 company, but I don't know how I can make multiple selections and save them.  Either with an add-and-remove listbox, a checked list box, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ListBox that lets you select multiple entries by holding ctrl. (Make sure you explain this on the page being displayed)

If editing, select the already added entries using MultiSelectList (see [Getting MultiSelectList to select items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340555/getting-multiselectlist-to-select-items))

Then to show the control on the view use Html.ListBox

A bit over complex but useful example: http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/tip-of-the-day-198-asp-net-mvc-listbox-controls/

Comment: Thank you.  It's easy to find information when you know to search for "MultiSelectList"!  But, much harder when you don't know the term to search for.